# ARRAYFORMULA with SUM OR SUMIF?

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I'm trying my to use `ARRAYFORMULA` with `SUM (or SUMIF?)`.  I basically want to lock `C1` and always `SUM` from `C1` down

```
=ARRAYFORMULA((SUM(C1:C2) + 1)&":"&(SUM(C1:C3)))         IN D3 is this
=ARRAYFORMULA((SUM(C1:C3) + 1)&":"&(SUM(C1:C4)))         IN D4 is this
```

Here is sample sheet and below is visual.

Col C is 50, 20, 16, etc.
Col D is 2:50, 51:70, 71:86, etc.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DANMNEahYAoYBCQO1BsfXfUrgPj2mVWNKjn7VuYIIyI/edit#gid=0

```
units   desired_result
50      2:50
20      51:70
16      71:86
8       87:94
2       95:96
```

If you could give a brief explanation on logic that'd be great.    Google's is confusing (as always) and Youtube is limited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives a result close to the one you want, but will need a bit of tweaking if you want to get 2:50 in F2 and 163:163 further down

```
=arrayformula(if(C2:C="","",sumif(row(C2:C),"<"&row(C2:C),C2:C)+1&":"&sumif(row(C2:C),"<="&row(C2:C),C2:C)))
```

[image]

I think it should be fairly self explanatory - the first part of the formula gives the sum for all rows where row number is less than row number of  the current row and the second part of the formula gives the sum for all rows less than or equal to the current row. The slightly tricky thing is to realise that when the criteria part "<"&row(C2:C) of the SUMIF is itself an array, the SUMIF is evaluated separately for each array element and gives a new row in the resulting  output array.

Comment: wow this is awesome thanks Tom!  And thank you so much for the description of the logic - I'd be lost without it!

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked for you. Please accept answer if you are able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

To lock a range, use `$`

```
=(SUM($C$1:C2) + 1)&":"&(SUM($C$1:C3))
```

Drag fill down.